# ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName returns different values for UNION and non-UNION queries

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Using Java JDBC, I want to collect information returned from SQL Select query.

If I fire below SQL query:

```
SELECT col1 AS 'Field1', col2 AS 'Field2' FROM Table;
```

Then, using resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(1), I get 'col1' as result, which is the expected result.

Now, the problem is, when I join 2 SQL tables (Since, MySQL does not provide Full Outer Join, hence, I fired the following query)

```
SELECT Table1.Col1 AS 'Field1', Table1.Col3 AS 'Field2',
Table2.Col5 AS 'Field3',Table2.Col4 AS 'Field4' FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id 
UNION 
SELECT Table1.Col1 AS 'Field1', Table1.Col3 AS 'Field2', 
Table2.Col5 AS 'Field3',Table2.Col4 AS 'Field4' FROM Table1 
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.id;
```

Now, using resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(1), I get 'Field1' as result, where as, I expected 'col1'.

I tried resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(1) also, but it still returned 'Field1'.

I want 'col1' as the result, which I could not get by any of the methods of resultSetMetaData.

Any help on this will be appreciable.

Comment: Did you try by not using alias name in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing those results because it is a UNION query. It is entirely possible that such a query could do something like

```sql
SELECT Col1 AS Field1 FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Col2 AS Field1 FROM Table2
```

In that case there is no single "correct" answer if `getColumnName` was to try and return the name of the underlying column in the result: Should it return 'Col1' or 'Col2'?

Since any column in the result set of a UNION query can be derived from more than one *underlying* column, `getColumnName` can only return the *effective* name of that column, which is `Field1` in the example above.